# What is the relationship between angles and pulse length of servo motor?

Tags: pi-3, pwm, servo

I've been working on a project where I've to drive the servo motors. I am using Raspberry Pi 3B+ model and Adafruit PCA9685 to drive the servos. For that I need to find which angle is at what pulse length and really been stuck here for a while.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

A pulse width of 1500 µs moves the horn to the centre.  You can call that any angle you want, say 0.

For each 10 µs **decrease** in pulse length the servo moves one degree **clockwise**.

For each 10 µs **increase** in pulse length the servo moves one degree **counter clockwise**.

These figures are approximate and vary by servo model.

The servo will have angle limits.  If you try to move a servo beyond its limits you can damage/destroy the servo.